# A good way to work with collection of models in php with phpdocs

Tags: php, collections, phpdoc

Assume I have a model like the following:

```
class PackageModel
{
    public $name;
    public $price;
}
```

And I have the following collection abstract class:

```
abstract class Collection
{
    protected $items = [];

    public function addItem($obj, $key = null) {
        if ($key == null) {
            $this->items[] = $obj;
        } else {
            if (isset($this->items[$key])) {
                throw new KeyAlreadyExistsException("Key $key already exists.");
            } else {
                $this->items[$key] = $obj;
            }
        }
    }

    public function deleteItem($key) {
        if (isset($this->items[$key])) {
            unset($this->items[$key]);
        } else {
            throw new InvalidKeyException("key $key does not exist");
        }
    }

    public function getItem($key) {
        if (isset($this->items[$key])) {
            return $this->items[$key];
        } else {
            throw new InvalidKeyException("key $key does not exist");
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to create a collection of `PackageModel` and thus create a collection which includes autocomplete in my code every time I get an item from the collection.

A simple solution would be to extend the collection and add phpdocs to the getItem function and call the parent function like this:

```
class PackageCollection extends Collection
{
    /**
     * @return PackageModel
     */
    public function getItem($key)
    {
        parent::addItem($key);
    }
}
```

But that would require me to do that every time I extend the collection class.

Is there a way to bypass it and somehow get it familiar with the specific model I am intending it for?

Comment: I have a few questions related to your code. Why is Collection abstract if you don't have abstract functions? and why are you calling addItem statically? Why are you overloading getItem and change the parameter number?

Comment: @ElzoValugi  
The reason for the overloading is for the phpdocs, that way you get autocomplete. The extra parameter is a typing mistake.

Comment: @ElzoValugi The abstraction is just because that specific class should not exist by itself, and there are no abstract functions because I need them implemented. in php when you need to call parent code this is the syntax for it. at least that's the only way I know of. I don't think it's really static.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39401647/934739