# Narrowing return type on inheritance for abstract method through PHPdoc causes PHP error

Tags: php, inheritance, phpdoc, type-narrowing

Assume we have the following inheritance chain in PHP

```php
abstract class Entity {}
abstract class RealEntity extends Entity {}
abstract class PseudoEntity extends Entity {}
```

and a bunch of other classes that mirror the same inheritance chain

```php
abstract class EntitySerializer {
  /**
   * @return Entity
   */
  abstract public function getEntity();
}

abstract class RealEntitySerializer extends EntitySerializer {
  /**
   * @return RealEntity
   */
  abstract public function getEntity();
}


abstract class PseudoEntitySerializer extends EntitySerializer {
  /**
   * @return PseudoEntity
   */
  abstract public function getEntity();
}
```

PHP complains that the abstract method `getEntity` must either be properly implemented (and loose the `abstract` keyword) or must not be re-declared. I can understand why PHP complains, because despite the PHPdoc comments the method signature is identical to the signature of the parent method in `EntitySerializer`.

However, I want somehow to make clear that child classes that extend `RealEntitySerializer` or `PseudoEntitySerializer` must not return an instance of an arbitrary `Entity` but narrow the return type to `RealEntity` or `PseudoEntity` resp.

Especially, If I omit re-definition of the method and its corresponding PHPdoc from the intermediate classes in order to make PHP happy, my IDE correctly assumes that `RealEntitySerializer::getEntity` and `PseudoEntitySerializer::getEntity` is allowed to return an arbitrary instance of `Entity`. In consequence, my IDE complains that I call undefined methods if I call methods that are particular to one of the intermediate classes on an object that was returned by `RealEntitySerializer::getEntity` or `PseudoEntitySerializer::getEntity` resp.

How, do I achieve both goals? Code that is (a) interpreted by PHP without an error and and that is (b) properly documented.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [PSR-5: PHPDoc](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/211063eed7f4d9b4514b728d7b1810d9b3379dd1/proposed/phpdoc.md#711-method) **`@method`** tag.

## Syntax

```
@method [return type] [name]([type] [parameter], [...]) [description]
```

## Examples

```
/**
 * @method string getString()
 * @method void setInteger(int $integer)
 * @method setString(int $integer)
 */
class Child extends Parent
{
    <...>
}
```

```
abstract class EntitySerializer {
  /**
   * @return Entity
   */
  abstract public function getEntity();
}

/**
 * @method RealEntity getEntity()
 */
abstract class RealEntitySerializer extends EntitySerializer {}

/**
 * @method PseudoEntity getEntity()
 */
abstract class PseudoEntitySerializer extends EntitySerializer {}
```